# How to update css rules that use hierarchical selectors with component input variable in angular

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I would like to use Angular component input attribute values to modify my CSS rules; however, my selector is hierarchical. Is this possible?

I have an SVG (country heat map) consisting of a lot of paths that represent counties. While zooming into the counties, I want to apply a class that sets the fill transition on those paths to a configurable duration (to fade in and out).

I am doing this by setting a class (`country--zooming`) on the parent country `<g>` tag as a marker and removing it after the duration. The duration is set on the paths with a CSS selector like this: `.country--zooming path {}`.

I know how to set classes and style properties on a single/specific tag in various ways in Angular – I am doing it with `country--zooming`. However, I don't know of any way to modify the duration in the CSS that has a selector that represents a hierarchy (in this case all `path` tags under a parent with a class of `country--zooming`).

Is there any way to apply a dynamic/configurable CSS rule with a selector that represents a hierarchy? If not, is there any other way to accomplish this?

Here's what I have so far:

Template:

```
<svg>
  <g class="country">
    <path ... />
    <path ... />
    ...
  </g>
</svg>
```

CSS:

```
.country--zooming path {
  transition: fill 2000ms ease-in-out;
}
```

Typescript:

```
let country = this.chart.nativeElement.querySelector(".country");

country.classList.add("country--zooming");

this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
  country.classList.remove("country--zooming");
}, 2000);

// set the new fill colors for paths here
```

This works as-is, but I want the duration to be configurable via an input property on the component, so I am looking for a way to set that duration in the CSS or to accomplish this in a way that will allow it to be configurable. I don't think selecting and looping through each path to apply the rule individually is feasible since there are 3.4k+ paths, and these are short animations. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

**I should add that the reason that I am switching the CSS rule on and off is that I don't want the fill duration to to be delayed when the map is not zooming. That is because I am also changing the fill color on hover and right-click (selecting it), so I want the fill change to be instant in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<svg>
    <g [class.country--zooming]="isCountryZooming" [style.transition-duration]="transitionDuration">
        <path ... />
        <path ... />
    ...
    </g>
</svg>
```

(and)

```
.country--zooming path {
  transition: fill inherit ease-in-out;
}
```

(and)

```
this.durationTime = 2000;
this.isCountryZooming = true;
this.transitionDuration = durationTime + 'ms';

this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
    this.isCountryZooming = false;
    this.transitionDuration = 'initial';
}, this.durationTime);

// set the new fill colors for paths here
```

set a configurable **transition-duration** on the parent element and inherit it to the children elements in css.. The **transition-duration** of children elements shall be **inherit** so that it will take the value of whatever the parent element has been configured..

Comment: This works, thanks! One strange thing I encountered is that the inline inherit (transition: fill inhert ease-in-out) was not picking up the inherited transition duration. I added transition-duration: inherit; to the same rule and it worked.

Comment: Alright! I will take a note of it.. to prefer specific rule over grouped inline rules.. for generic values maybe..